# what is the “learning” that takes place in Naive Bayes?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, naive-bayes

As I recall algorithms like nearest neighbor don't build a model based on training data and then apply that model to test data. It just takes each new instance and compares it to *all* the data to find the closest one, etc.

What about Naive Bayes? It seems to be similar. For example neural networks learn parameters and then use the corresponding model on test data. But for Naive Bayes I don't see where the learning takes place. There are no learned parameters. It seems to again look at the entire dataset for each prediction. Can anyone comment on this?

Additionally, then what is the use of a training/test split. I can see that we would want a test set because we want it to be labeled but beyond that I don't see why we need test/train?

Comment: "counting" (eg. to get prior distribution) is a type of "learning"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Different from the nearest neighbor algorithm, the Naive Bayes algorithm is not a *lazy* method; A real learning takes place for Naive Bayes. The parameters that are learned in Naive Bayes are the *prior probabilities* of different classes, as well as the *likelihood* of different features for each class. In the test phase, these learned parameters are used to estimate the probability of each class for the given sample.

In other words, in Naive Bayes, for each sample in the test set, the parameters determined during training are used to estimate the probability of that sample belonging to different classes. For example, $P(c|x)\propto P(c)P(x_1|c)P(x_2|c)...p(x_n|c)$ where $c$ is a class and $x$ is a test sample. All quantities $P(c)$ and $P(x_i|c)$ are parameters which are determined during training and are used during testing. This is similar to NN, but the kind of learning and the kind of applying the learned model is different.

As an example, take a look at the [Naive Bayes implementation in nltk](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html). See the `train` and `prob_classify` methods. In the `train` method, `label_probdist` and `feature_probdist` are computed, and in the `prob_classify` method, these parameters are used to estimate the probability of different class for a test sample. Just note that `_label_probdist` and `_feature_probdist` are respectively initialized to `label_probdist` and `feature_probdist` in the constructor.

About your second question (the final paragraph), even for the lazy methods such as the nearest neighbor method, we need to split data into train/test. This is because we want to evaluate the performance of the model obtained based on the training data on some samples that are not seen during training to obtain a reasonable measure of the model generalization.

Comment: I don't see that the learning would take place in the training has anything to do with what happens on the testing. With NN the model which was learned is applied to the test but nothing special is applied to the test in Naive Bayes it seems. Further, unless I don't recall properly nearest neighbor does not use any information it used in the training to improve the result in the test

Comment: @matt I modified the answer to be more clear. Look at the second paragraph. Is it now clear?

Comment: It seems to me that the entire process is recalculated in the test set. Is that wrong? Nothing is carried over from the training set to the test set, whereas in something like a neural network, the learned parameters are carried over

Comment: @matt No! The process is **not** repeated for the test set. The whole parameters are carried over from the training set to the test set. In this aspect, it is completely like NNs.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Do you know of an implementation of this that shows that it learns the parameters and carries them over to the testing task? I downloaded e1071 and then tried to view naiveBayes but it just gives me a kind of wrapper like this:naiveBayes
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("naiveBayes")
<environment: namespace:e1071>

Comment: @matt Take a look at [Naive Bayes implementation in skikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/naive_bayes.py)

Comment: @matt Take a look at the modified answer. I gave an example of a real implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Hossein . I am looking at R code here: https://github.com/cran/e1071/blob/master/R/naiveBayes.R because I don't read Python very well.

Comment: Hello again. What happens if the sample is small so that for example not all levels of the variable x1 occur. Does that mean the algorithm predicts zero for every class?

Comment: @matt: Add-one smoothing is proposed for resolving such situations.

Comment: not sure if you remember this question. I finally understand what you mean. However, does this mean that if you were going to program a model for the Naive Bayes, you would need to keep a record of the conditional probability of each level of each input variable given each level of the class variable for the training set?

Comment: So for example, if the class variable had 10 values and there were 50 input variables each with 5 levels, then you would need 10x50x5=2500 conditional probability calculations?

Comment: And then in the classification process on test data, you would look up these numbers in the test set for the particular set of input levels and the output level, and then multiply according to the naive bayes calculation you wrote above?

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: @matt Yes, it is nearly correct. Just note that since probabilities should sum to one, it is not necessary to store all 2500 conditional probabilities in your example. You need to store 10x50x4 values.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_learning#Examples_of_Lazy_Learning_Methods mentions Lazy naive Bayes as an example for Lazy Learning methods. Is Wikipedia wrong here and needs to be updated?

Comment: @asmaier It seems to be different from classic Naive Bayes. Maybe they select the training instances, to be used to calculate probabilities, based on the test instance, hence the name *lazy*.

Comment: How would you learn the $P(x_i | c)$  when the features are continuous rather than discrete, such as when using Guassian Naive Bayes? In this case the "parameters" would be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I did not see any parameters in the Naive Bayes Classifier.

I think we do not need to learn parameters like what we do in Neural networks, but we learn(or calculate) the prior probability from the training data. Then we apply the prior we calculated from training data to make predictions in test data.

Comment: The estimated probabilities are parameters.

Comment: @Tim There is nothing beyond the estimated probabilities that contributes to the expression of the classifier, which defeats the point of the "parameter" characterization. You can't just decide to call all the members of a function "parameters". In the example $f(x) = ax + b$, $a$ can be considered as a parameter, but not $ax$.  Saying that $P(x_i | c)$ is a parameter in the function $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = argmax_{c \in C(\omega)} (\propto P(x_1 | c)P(x_2|c) \dots P(x_n | c))$ is falling to the same mistake.

Comment: @MehdiCharife Bernoulli or categorical distributions have parameters that *are* also the probabilities, for NB you need to estimate those probabilities. In Gaussian NB this is even more explicit, as you are finding the parameters of the Gaussians, then you multiply the probability densities to get joint probability distribution.

Comment: @Tim I don't see how that responds to my comment. Perhabs you meant to respond to the one I typed below the accepted answer?

Comment: @MehdiCharife I'm commenting on your claim that there are no parameters in Naive Bayes.

Comment: @Tim My claim was that the terms that you were referring to as "parameters" are in fact not parameters, not that Naive Bayes don't have them.